# How to execute aggreagatewordcount example in hadoop which uses hadoop aggregate framework?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I tried executing the aggregatewordcount example found in hadoop examples jar file. Even though the program ran successfully, the output was not what I expected. The output file just has a single line which goes like this:

```
record_count 9
```

where 9 is the number of lines in the input file that I gave as input to the program. The program is supposed to give the word count of each unique word in the input file. I executed the program with following command:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar aggregatewordcount input_dir output_dir 1 textinputformat
```

I am using hadoop 2.2.0. What should I do to get the program working correctly?

Comment: thats the behavior of wordcount not aggregatewordcount

Comment: Both wordcount and aggregatewordcount are supposed to give same output. wordcount used custom maper and reducer. aggregatewordcount uses hadoop aggregate framework. Can you please explain your point.